How do I know if "through" is an adverb or a preposition? or even particle?
When through is used as a preposition, it is followed by a noun. When it is used as an adverb, it is not followed by a noun (It's what they say). But there are articles which introduces "through" mostly as a particle, and now with this new category of particle which is related to phrasal verbs I'm totally confused how to organize usages of this important word. I can easily identify them as an adjective but need a little more professional help for adv, pre and particle. Could you help me to figure out the exact grammatical relation with this tough word in each example as a practice?

I'm through (adj)

The first half of the alphabet are the letters A through M (pre)

And, of course, you walk through a door.‌ (pre I think)

The tunnel goes through the mountain. (idk maybe particle)

They talked through the entire movie (idk maybe particle)

The athlete pushed through the pain to win the race. (idk)

Let's see this project through to the end. (Is it idiom?)

She saw the project through to the very end. (exactly number 7)

I'm soaked through. (definitely adv)

We must follow this plan through (adv I think)

If you've memorized the multiplication table, you know the whole thing through (adv I think)



IMO, 9-11 are the same as 7, with the "end" or other extremity of a scale implied and omitted ("soaked through to the bone").

Yes, see something through is an idiom.

In the linked article's section "'Through' as a Particle," I find most of their examples unconvincing. As I see it, "particle" is just a sort of shrug, saying that this word brings no meaning of its own, and is just part of a multi-word phrase with its own distinct meaning. But whether we "see through" a lie or a window, it seems to me we're using standard meanings of "see" and "through" (even if we're using them metaphorically with the lie), and similar with many of their other examples..

@AndyBonner Some say "through to..." might be a prepositional phrase, however most usages are idiomatic and phrase-related. not just a regular word with a direct meaning. I wonder what does "through" literally mean to a native speaker? that word can be too metaphorical.

"What does [a given word] mean" is a very difficult question, and usually not the most useful question. (That's why it's so hard to make, and sometimes use, dictionaries!) Meaning is created in larger "chunks"; entire sentences have meanings, and even then rely on the context of the others around them. As you've shown here, "through" can "have" many meanings, or maybe it's more accurate to say that it can play a role to contribute to many different meanings.

@AndyBonner I've written 35 meanings for through. Most of them are figurative that's why it's a complicated word. 6 hour study just for a single word today! You see even Cambridge dictionary can not identify them correctly (precisely).  They categorize them as a group of 1)adverb/preposition 2) adjective/adverb etc.
